# how to convert latitude, longitude projection from epsg:3857 to epsg:4326

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, coordinate-system, geocoding, google-maps-api

I want to use geocode in our application. so that, I got Google geocoding API and could achieve with Google Maps.
Problem is that I wanted to achieve the same with my own map which is having projection EPSG:4326 INSTEAD OF getting geocoded from Google Map which is having projection EPSG:3857.
or
 I am getting a coordinates from Google geocoding projection EPSG:3857 and that 
coordinates I want to mark on my OpenLayers Map which is having projection EPSG:4326

please help me.

Answer (score 6):

The following piece of code allows you to transform your latitude and longitude coordinates from epsg:3857 to epsg:4326 in just one line. 
Just substitute longitude and latitudine values to LON and LAT in the code.

```
point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(LON,LAT).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

In point you'll have an OpenLayers readable point.

Comment: Your Answer was flagged up as low-quality because of its length.  I recommend that you add a paragraph to give more context about how it addresses the Question.

Comment: Ya, I'm sorry, didn't have so much time yeasterday :)

Answer (score 2):

Asuming you have the latitude and Longitude in the appropriate variables, you can use the following code to project the point:

```
var epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
var epsgWebMercator = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857');
var pt_latLong=new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat);
var pt_webMercator= pt_latLong.transform(epsg4326,epsgWebMercator);
```